# How can I split a big list separated by commas into a table with 5 columns?

Tags: python, list

I have this big list, and I would like to split it into 5 columns. (like how a table would be on paper for example). I want the first entry to go in the first column, and second entry to go in the second column, third entry to go in the third column, fourth entry to go into the fourth column, fifth entry to go into fifth column. THEN the sixth entry in the big list would go in the first column, and seventh entry into the second column...etc.

I'm not too sure on how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mOuQ.png)

Comment: You can find help in the hundreds of tutorials out there. [ask]

Comment: This might be of some help... https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_ref_string_split2

Comment: Please don't post images of code or textual data in your question — put them _int_ your question.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting a list into n-sized chunks is a [standard recipe on the `itertools page`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), called `grouper`

```
from itertools import *
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

This would work as follows:

```
test_data = list(range(13,91))
test_output = list(grouper(test_data, 5))
print (test_output)

[(13, 14, 15, 16, 17), (18, 19, 20, 21, 22), (23, 24, 25, 26, 27), (28, 29, 30, 31, 32), (33, 34, 35, 36, 37), (38, 39, 40, 41, 42), (43, 44, 45, 46, 47), (48, 49, 50, 51, 52), (53, 54, 55, 56, 57), (58, 59, 60, 61, 62), (63, 64, 65, 66, 67), (68, 69, 70, 71, 72), (73, 74, 75, 76, 77), (78, 79, 80, 81, 82), (83, 84, 85, 86, 87), (88, 89, 90, None, None)]
```

This gives tuples rather than lists for the groups of fives, but that should work for most purposes.

A perhaps easier to understand approach would simply involve stepping through the list in 5s and collecting a 5-long slice each time.

```
test_output = [test_data[a:a+5] for a in range(0,len(test_data),5)]
print(test_output)

[[13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20, 21, 22], [23, 24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 31, 32], [33, 34, 35, 36, 37], [38, 39, 40, 41, 42], [43, 44, 45, 46, 47], [48, 49, 50, 51, 52], [53, 54, 55, 56, 57], [58, 59, 60, 61, 62], [63, 64, 65, 66, 67], [68, 69, 70, 71, 72], [73, 74, 75, 76, 77], [78, 79, 80, 81, 82], [83, 84, 85, 86, 87], [88, 89, 90]]
```

Edit: It occurs to me that you might actually be wanting to print the list as a 5-field table. To cope with the possibly short last line, I'd take the sections of the list into a short working list:

```
for a in range(0,len(test_data),5):
    pr_data = test_data[a:a+5]
    print(("{:>8}"*len(pr_data)).format(*pr_data))

    
      13      14      15      16      17
      18      19      20      21      22
      23      24      25      26      27
      28      29      30      31      32
      33      34      35      36      37
      38      39      40      41      42
      43      44      45      46      47
      48      49      50      51      52
      53      54      55      56      57
      58      59      60      61      62
      63      64      65      66      67
      68      69      70      71      72
      73      74      75      76      77
      78      79      80      81      82
      83      84      85      86      87
      88      89      90
```

Here I've specified a field width of 8 in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

```
myList=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15"]
print("".join([x[1]+"\n"*(x[0]%5==4)+"\t"*(x[0]%5!=4) for x in enumerate(myList)]))
```

Output:

```
 1   2   3   4   5
 6   7   8   9   10
 11  12  13  14  15
```